# How to Plot a Bar Graph with Two Categorical Variables on X-Axis (one nested by the other, but both visible), and other variables as fill?

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart, categorical-data

I have a dataset with two categorical variables, **region** and **function**. In total there are 92 regions, divided into 13 functional categories. In addition to these regions belonging to a functional category, they are also identified as either **white**, **gray**, or **other**.  Each region is associated with a density value that will be plotted on the y-axis. For Example:

| Region | Function | Matter | Density |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMB | Cranial | Gray | 4 |
| bsc | Visual | White | 0.4 |
| LG | Visual | Gray | 30.5 |
| RET | Thalamic | Gray | 25 |
| eml | Thalamic | White | 15 |
| cpt | Motor | Other | 5 |

I wish to create a graph similar to this, where the year dates at the top would be my functional categories, the x-axis labels would be my region names, and the bar fill would denote white/gray. However, an important distinction is I would want all of my 92 regions to be present along the x-axis once, divided into functional groups.

[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJw69.png)

I've created graphs showing just the total averages of the regions within my functional groups as well as a graph of all regions averages separately. I would like to create something similar, but with all the functional group's associated regions present in the graph and grouped by function. Essential a merger between these two types of graphs, in addition to a fill variable for the bars.

[Graph of Region Averages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV9pk.png)

[Graph of Functional Group Averages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co1Ct.png)

Answer (score 1):

Six data is not much. I don't have an example to pull a good example from, but maybe you're looking for something like that:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(Density, fill= Matter)) + 
    geom_bar(width=.5) + 
    facet_grid(~Function + Region, scales="free_x", space="free")
```